# Permission 0700 Error with MapReduce

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, hbase

I have an error while running the mapreduce jar file in Eclipse luna. I have set up My HBASE and HADOOP using Cygwin.

Here is the error message from Eclipse console:

```
15/03/23 16:02:01 INFO mapreduce.TableOutputFormat: Created table instance for TWEETS_TIMEWISE
15/03/23 16:02:03 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201503231018_0009
15/03/23 16:02:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/03/23 16:02:04 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201503231018_0009_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED
Error initializing attempt_201503231018_0009_m_000002_0:
java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-z010823-dev\mapred\local\taskTracker\z010823 to 0700
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:664)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:514)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobLocalizer.createLocalDirs(JobLocalizer.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DefaultTaskController.initializeJob(DefaultTaskController.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$4.run(TaskTracker.java:1336)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$5.run(TaskTracker.java:2603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am not able to solve this permission issue. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Hadoop's [own website](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows), "Cygwin is neither required nor supported." I've ran Hadoop on Windows before - I've installed Cygwin just to get the Unix tools like cp and rm on my path, but I've never ran Hadoop *from* Cygwin before. Try [this guide I wrote recently](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BweVwq32koypYm1QWHNvRTZWTm8/view?usp=sharing) that should help you get Hadoop running on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on a Windows box, but running under Cygwin, it seems there's a case of confused identity (Hadoop thinking it's running under UNIX, and trying to set UNIX permissions which will obviously fail). I'd recommend getting rid of Cygwin, but if you've got your heart set on it, maybe ask on Hadoop's own forums if it's even possible to run your odd beast.

Comment: If any one have this issues please help me out

Comment: Do you really need to run under cygwin?

Comment: Well, a quick glance at google shows you're not the first one to run across this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have move Cygwin to RHEL. now it works well.

thanks aoetalks.